# Why my ant 'for' loop does not print "Test" ten times?

Tags: for-loop, ant, ant-contrib

I am trying to do a loop in ant. I used the ant-contrib 'for'. I wanted to read from a file to create the list. My file ("CounterFile.txt") has simply numbers 1 to 10, one in each line. From the 'echo' command below, I expected it to print "Test 1", "Test 2", .. "Test 10". But it prints the 'Test' only once. Can anyone please explain why that's the case?

```
<target name="Start">
    <loadfile property="CounterFile" srcfile="./CounterFile.txt"/>
    <for param="count" list="${CounterFile}" delimiter="${count.separator}">
     <sequential>
        <echo>Test @{count}</echo>              
     </sequential>
    </for>
  </target>
```

[image]

Comment: I found the code to load and read from a file from the following link: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/01/03/apache-ant-for-loop-example-for-reading-a-text-file/

Answer (score 0):

Just accidentally found the solution. The delimiter should have ${line.separator} not ${count.separator}. Changing that worked for me! :-)